# If it's possible to display Ajax response ( html page ) on SweetAlert2?

Tags: javascript, html, web, sweetalert2

I would like to display Ajax response on Sweet Alert2.Ajax response generated automatically and it might be some question with confirming button or just info message. I would like to display exactly the same what I receive on Ajax. 
Do someone knows how I can implement it?
Regards.

```
   success: function (result) {
       swal({
            html:true,
            title: title,
            type: type,
            text:  $(result).find('html'),
            confirmButtonColor: "#33537d",
            confirmButtonText: "Close",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should just be able to put use the response data in the sweet alert like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourPhpFile.php",
    data: { 'dataString': dataString },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        var responseData = "data : " + data;
        swal(
        html:true,
        title: title,
        type: type,
        text:  responseData,
        confirmButtonColor: "#33537d",
        confirmButtonText: "Close",
        closeOnConfirm: false
        )
    }
});
```

Good luck.